# EmberJS: Get and set properties defined with dot notation

Tags: ember.js

If I have a property defined with dot notation, how do I do an @get or @set on it in Ember?

```
model = DS.Model.extend EmberValidations.Mixin,
  ...

  validations:
    'user.fullName':
      presence:
        message: null

  initializer: (->
    @set 'validations.user.fullName.presence.message', @get('i18n').t('validations.fullName.format') # this doesn't work
  ).on('init')
```

The problem is I can't do a @get or @set on 'validations.user.fullName' since it doesn't know how to access that property. But because of the way ember-validations works, I have to define the property that way, and I have to set it that way if I want to use i18n.

I can do `@get('validations')['user.fullName'].presence.message` to get the value if I need to, but really I need to set it.

I'm sure there must be a way to set it using dot notation in the property name, but I can't find anything anywhere saying how.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been able to do that. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator/issues/20) on ember-model-validator regarding i18n support. But I've been able to workaround the problem with the following code (using a [custom validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-model-validator#custom)):

```
translate(label) {
  return this.get('i18n').t(label).toString();
},

validations: {
 code: {
  'user.fullName': {
    validation(key, value) {
      return !Ember.isEmpty(value);
    }, message(key, value) {
      let translation = value.translate('path.to.required.message.translation');
      return translation;
    }
  }
}
```